# Get profile picture from Azure Active Directory

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-active-directory

We have set the Azure AD as a identity provider in our application. We want to display profile picture that should come from Azure AD, in the application.

In order to test, I have added one Windows Live Id account (which has a profile picture) in the Azure AD. We then tried it using Graph Explorer, but no luck.

How do we get the profile picture from Azure AD?

Comment: Can you add more detail about exactly what you tried and how it failed?

Comment: Just simple thing, want logged-in user profile picture along with the other claims

Comment: Do you have enough permissions to access photo?

Answer (score 10):

You can use Azure Active Directory Graph Client to get user thumbnail photo

```
var servicePoint = new Uri("https://graph.windows.net");
// e.g. xxx.onmicrosoft.com
var serviceRoot = new Uri(servicePoint, "<your tenant>"); 

// ClientID and SecretKey are defined when you register application
// with Azure AD
const string clientId  = "<clientId>";
const string secretKey = "<secretKey>";

var authContext = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/<tenant>/oauth2/token");
var credential  = new ClientCredential(clientId, secretKey);

ActiveDirectoryClient directoryClient = new ActiveDirectoryClient(serviceRoot, async () => {
    var result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync("https://graph.windows.net/", credential);
    return result.AccessToken;
});

var user = await directoryClient.Users
    .Where(x => x.UserPrincipalName == "<username>")
    .ExecuteSingleAsync();

DataServiceStreamResponse photo = await user.ThumbnailPhoto.DownloadAsync();

using (MemoryStream s = new MemoryStream()){
    photo.Stream.CopyTo(s);
    var encodedImage = Convert.ToBase64String(s.ToArray());
}
```

Azure AD returns user's photo in binary format, you need to convert to Base64 string

Answer (score 3):

Getting photos through Graph Explorer is not supported.  Assuming that "signedInUser" already contains the signed in user entity, then this code snippet using the client library should work for you...

```
        #region get signed in user's photo
        if (signedInUser.ObjectId != null)
        {
            IUser sUser = (IUser)signedInUser;
            IStreamFetcher photo = (IStreamFetcher)sUser.ThumbnailPhoto;
            try
            {
                DataServiceStreamResponse response =
                photo.DownloadAsync().Result;
                Console.WriteLine("\nUser {0} GOT thumbnailphoto", signedInUser.DisplayName);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nError getting the user's photo - may not exist {0} {1}", e.Message,
                    e.InnerException != null ? e.InnerException.Message : "");
            }
        }
        #endregion
```

Alternatively you can do this through REST and it should look like this:
GET https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/users//thumbnailPhoto?api-version=1.5
Hope this helps,

Comment: Thanks Dan. Just one silly question, where do I get signedInUser entity from?

Comment: full explanation: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/profilephoto_get

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Azure AD Graph API Docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations), Microsoft recommends transitioning to [Microsoft Graph](https://graph.microsoft.io/), as the Azure AD Graph API is being phased out.

However, to easily grab the photo via Azure AD, for now, use this URL template:

`https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/users/{user_id}/thumbnailPhoto?api-version={version}`

For example (this is a fake user id):

`https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/users/abc1d234-01ab-1a23-12ab-abc0d123e456/thumbnailPhoto?api-version=1.6`

The code below assumes you already have an authenticated user, with a token. This is a simplistic example; you'll want to change the return value to suit your needs, add error checking, etc.

```
const string ThumbUrl = "https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/users/{0}/thumbnailPhoto?api-version=1.6";

// Attempts to retrieve the thumbnail image for the specified user, with fallback.
// Returns: Fully formatted string for supplying as the src attribute value of an img tag.
private string GetUserThumbnail(string userId)
{
    string thumbnail = "some base64 encoded fallback image";
    string mediaType = "image/jpg"; // whatever your fallback image type is
    string requestUrl = string.Format(ThumbUrl, userId);

    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", GetToken());
    HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(requestUrl).Result;

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        // Read the response as a byte array
        var responseBody = response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

        // The headers will contain information on the image type returned
        mediaType = response.Content.Headers.ContentType.MediaType;

        // Encode the image string
        thumbnail = Convert.ToBase64String(responseBody);
    }

    return $"data&colon;{mediaType};base64,{thumbnail}";
}

// Factored out for use with other calls which may need the token
private string GetToken()
{
    return HttpContext.Current.Session["Token"] == null ? string.Empty : HttpContext.Current.Session["Token"].ToString();
}
```